# How to add values to array from UserDefaults?

Tags: swift

I've been trying to add values to array from UserDefaults.standard.

my step:

1. adding a value in UserDefaults.
2. checking the Userdefautls to see if it has a value(from 0 to 100)
3. if it has a value in UserDefaults, adding the value to the array.

   ```
   @IBAction func addfavorite(_ sender: Any) {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(myIndex, forKey:arr[myIndex])
   }

   for myIndex in 0..<100 {
       if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:arr[myIndex]) != nil { 
           favoriteArr.append(myIndex)
       }
   }
   ```

Comparing non-optional value of type 'Bool' to 'nil' always returns true

Answer (score 1):

The issue there is that `bool(forKey:)` method will always return `false` if there is no value for a key because it returns a non optional `Bool`. An alternative to check against nil is to use `UserDefaults` method `object(forKey:)` which returns `Any?`

If your intent is just to persist an array of integers you can extend UserDefaults and create a computed property with a getter and a setter to make your data persist automatically:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var favorites: [Int] {
        get { array(forKey: "favorites") as? [Int] ?? [] }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: "favorites") }
    }
}
```

---

```
UserDefaults.standard.favorites = []
UserDefaults.standard.favorites.append(2)
UserDefaults.standard.favorites.append(7)
UserDefaults.standard.favorites // [2,7]
```